# Where can I get dummy.php

Tags: php, zend-studio

I moved to a new workspace in zend studio. Then debugging won't work because

> The file 'http://localhost/dummy.php',which is required by the zend
>   debugger,could not be found.please verify that the zend debugger is
>   properly installed on the server and that the 'dummy.php' is located
>   in your web server's document root

The file was usually there by itself.

I do not know why.

Where do I get this dummy.php? What should I do so the file is there.

Comment: Have you installed the *Zend debugger* properly?

Comment: You may create one *empty* `dummy.php`.

Comment: actually how do you install zend debugger properly?

Comment: there is no place to download it.

Comment: try reinstall it and if not works, **create** an **empty** dummy.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is *dummy.php* you needed:

```
<?php
@ini_set('zend_monitor.enable', 0);
if(@function_exists('output_cache_disable')) {
    @output_cache_disable();
}
if(isset($_GET['debugger_connect']) && $_GET['debugger_connect'] == 1) {
    if(function_exists('debugger_connect'))  {
        debugger_connect();
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "No connector is installed.";
    }
}
?>
```